# Delete an user from Firebase Authentication in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to delete user from firebase Authentication for user UID

I'm trying by API method

> "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/deleteAccount?key=MyToken"

But It gives me error for `"INVALID_ID_TOKEN"`

How Can I get idToken in swift for another user by having him UID and make delete request?

Please help find a solution

Im need to delete from Authentication

In Firebase I have users.
If characteristic in user Admin == true  -> user can delete another user

[Authentication image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Dob2.png)
[Firebase users image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqoDW.png)

Comment: Please don’t include images in your questions. Include code and structures as text. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: I am also marking this as a duplicate because it has been asked and answered a number of times. The answer is, no, one user cannot directly delete another. There are options to authenticate as that user to delete it, and also check out the Firebase Admin SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I couldnt comment due to new account. But assuming your user is created and stored in the node of "Users" followed by their ID...

```
guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

FirebaseDatabase.Database.database().reference(withPath: "User").child(userID).removeValue()
```

that would be how you can delete YOUR own account. (I dont find a reason in doing this though...Maybe it's for deletion of own account i guess). Nevertheless, if you meant by deleting another person's account (again, not sure why a user could delete another user's account),then can u send your firebase database so we can see your nodes? I will edit my answer accordingly after that

Comment: Im add structure and Authentication image

Comment: @Oleg This is unfortunately not correct as it doesn't address the question; the OP wants to know how to *Delete an user from Firebase Authentication* and your example shows how to remove a value at a node, which is unrelated (note that not all apps store extra user data in a /users node). Additionally, the OP is asking how to delete *another user* via their UID. Can you update your answer to address the question?